# How can I copy tcl-variable to linux terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcl, tk-toolkit, csh

I use the below commands to copy string "ABC" to clipboard.

[file: aa.tcl] 
set myVar Hello 
clipboard clear 
clipboard append $myVar

clipboard get 
Hello

It works well in the tool.
But it doesn't work when I try to paste it into terminal sciprt.txt with mousewhell-click

How can I paste the variable in tcl into terminal-text file?

not working, xclip, bind, event etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clipboard` command works on the CLIPBOARD selection. This selection is usually taken when pasting the "Windows way": Using Ctrl-V or via the Paste option from the Edit menu or a context menu.

When pasting with the middle mouse button, the PRIMARY selection is taken instead. You have to use the `selection` command to work with the PRIMARY selection. Unfortunately, this is a bit more cumbersome than the `clipboard` command.

```
proc selproc {str offset count} {
    return [string range $str $offset [expr {$offset + $count - 1}]]
}

set myVar Hello
selection handle . [list selproc $myVar]
selection own .
```